# Why the repaint() don't work properly in this method

Tags: java, swing

The proposal of this code is use the method getStringHeight without use `Graphics g` in your requirement. Then I make this code but when this execute the command `System.out.println(this.getStringHeight(font, string));` the return is always 0, because the `repaint()` don't work properly. I want to know why and how to fix it.

Basically, before the return occurs I need to use the paintComponent to calculate the String Height and then return the value.

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {

    String string = "HELLO WORLD";
    Font font = new Font("arial", Font.LAYOUT_LEFT_TO_RIGHT, 30);
    private int height;
    private boolean gsh;

    public Panel() {

        System.out.println(this.getStringHeight(font, string));

    }

    public int getStringHeight(Font font, String string){
        this.gsh = true;
        repaint();
        return this.height;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (this.gsh == true) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            FontMetrics metrics = g2d.getFontMetrics(font);
            this.height = (int)font.createGlyphVector(metrics.getFontRenderContext(), string).getVisualBounds().getHeight();
            this.gsh = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JFrame display = new JFrame();
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        display.setSize(600,400);
        display.add(new Panel());
        display.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Don't call your class Frame. First of all it is not a Frame it is a panel. Secondly it is confusing because the is already an AWT class called Frame. Thirdly a class name should be descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> repaint() don't work properly.

There are at least two reasons why repaint() doesn't do anything:

1. The repaint() method does not paint the component right away. A paint request is made to the `RepaintManager` which will schedule the painting of the component to be done later.
2. In this case your code is executed in the constructor of your class. The component has not even been added to the frame yet so the RepaintManager will ignore the request since a panel can only be painted on a visible frame.

So the method returns without your painting code being executed and the value will always be 0.

Once the frame is made visible the panel will be painted and the painting code will execute.

> I need to use the paintComponent to calculate the String Height and then return the value.
>   import java.awt.Font;

A painting method is used for painting only. It is not used to set properties of the component. It should not calculate a height or set a switch.

If you are trying to do some kind of size calculation for your component, then the logic should be added to the `getPreferredSize()` method of your class. This is the method that calculates the size of the component based on the properties of the component.

Comment: I need to use this command to get the font height (int)font.createGlyphVector(metrics.getFontRenderContext(), string).getVisualBounds().getHeight(); and FontMetrics requires Graphics2D and Graphics2D requires a paintComponent, then I got this idea to get the value without use Graphics g in the requirement, I tried to use this command outside the constructor class and this only works if I put a thread.sleep(100) to the repaint be executed, but it's not cool, so I gave up trying to do this and now I have to use the getStringHeight inside a paintComponent to get the size value.

Comment: @Forsaiken, `I need to use this command to get the font height` - no you don't, at least not in a painting method. Your approach is completely wrong as I explained. You still have stated why you think you need to get the height. I gave you a possible solution which is how it is done in other Swing components.